# How can I route the different intent routes using @sys.any entity. Store the user utterances in DF-CX only

Tags: dialogflow-cx

Use case: I have an open question like How Can I help you today.?
So I created a page called **Appname**.

[image]

I add a parameter **@sys.any** with **required check box**

[image]

Now I want to route the different intents for how can I help you question.
For example, if user asking I want to reset my password, it will go to password reset intent route
Or
if user says I have an issue with laptop, it will go to laptop intent route.

Similarly, I have 10 different type of intents.

I already create those intents

Now, How Can I Route this type of situation.

I tried directly give the intents on Routes section, but it was not routing.

[image]

Can anyone help on this

**NOTE: I want to store that entire User-Utterances for How Can I help you question(Mandatory )**